# How to combine the tables in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

Consider two tables

```
tab1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 4}]
tab2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 4}]
```

How to quickly make a table where the ith row of `tab1` follows by 2(i-1)+1th and 2*ith rows of `tab2`, and for each corresponding 3 rows, one adds the row `{tab1[[i]][[1]],0,0,0}`? The ugly way to do this is

```
Flatten[Table[{{tab1[[i]][[1]],0,0,0},tab1[[i]],tab2[[2*(i-1)+1]],tab2[[2*i]]},{i,1,Length[tab1],1}],1]
```

Comment: are you sure you only wanted to give a single argument to `Table` and a symbolic `i` ?

Comment: @userrandrand : thanks! I have fixed the code.

Comment: Does `Flatten[Riffle[{{#[[1]],0,0,0},#}&/@tab1,Partition[tab2,2]],1]` pass your ugly test? I think it produces exactly the same output as your code. Test this carefully before you trust it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want pairs of items from your first list

```
{{#[[1]],0,0,0},#}&/@tab1
```

and pairs of items from your second list

```
Partition[tab2,2]
```

Alternate those pairs of pairs

```
Riffle[{{#[[1]],0,0,0},#}&/@tab1,Partition[tab2,2]]
```

and strip off the extra layer of `{}` introduced by the pairing

```
Flatten[Riffle[{{#[[1]],0,0,0},#}&/@tab1,Partition[tab2,2]],1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
n1 = 5;
n2 = 2*n1;
n3 = n2 + 2*n1;
tab1 = ArrayReshape[Range[n1*4], {n1, 4}]; (* tab1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n1, 4}]; *)
tab2 = ArrayReshape[100*Range[n2*4], {n2, 4}]; (*  tab2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n2, 4}];*)
tab3 = PadRight[Take[tab1, All, 1], {n1, 4}]; (* Explicitly construct a third table to facilitate Riffle-ing *)

(* I made the tables non-random so that you can see what's going on. *)

Riffle[Riffle[tab2, tab1, {1, -2, 3}], tab3, {1, -2, 4}]
```